# Global.cs file replacement in .Net Standard Class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

I am new to .net standard/.net core/blazer. In .net framework class library we used to have Global.cs file to store global variables, needs to do the same in .net standard class library, whats the Microsoft recommended way?

OR to summarise above:

where to store Global variables in .Net standard class library project?

Comment: your question is a suggestion. or might be not clear.

Comment: what is not clear here?

Comment: You might want to check IConfiguration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and read about Program.cs and Startup class in  ASP.NET Core apps. Not precisely .NET Standard, but might help.

Comment: what is the your issue in one line?

Comment: But I want it to be available with in my ,net standard library project not across the Website project that contains Startup.cs and Program.cs

Comment: @AjayKumar where to store Global variables in .Net standard class library project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Class library projects** you put it in `Web.config (or App.config)` and it will be available from the class library as well. You basically add manually such file (app.config/webconfig).

Comment: My understanding is that its not recommended to use config files in .net standard?

Comment: if you can create a discussion form i might help you to not create such file.

Comment: Create a config file?

Comment: yes basically class library is an empty project without any configuration as assumed. so incase if one need to have some configs on that project then we do it by creating new config file.

Comment: This is not the approach I would like to take. thanks anyways.

Comment: i know already this. that why i asked you to create the form to better understand you requirement to make configs on such project.

Comment: i might give you alternative solution.

Comment: requirements must be told otherwise we can't able to answer based on individual aspect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a class library, I would recommend having any variables etc passed in via configuration parameters/configuration objects, and if you need defaults - have defaults created in your constructors.

I would personally shy away from having a class lib access web.config/appSettings.json, as you're then tieing your application to a specific implementation.